# Angular-cli ng generate library não funciona

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, library, angular-cli

Tenho um projeto na versão 5 do angular, que gera uma library usando o rollup e funciona corretamente. Porém estou na migração da versão 5 para a versão 6 do angular e queria utilizar o angular-cli, que já gera uma biblioteca no mesmo padrão do rollup. Porém ao copiar o código para dentro de src/app e rodar o comando ng generate library, apenas é criado uma nova pasta project com um projeto genérico, nenhum dos meus arquivos é copiado automaticamente para a pasta project. Gostaria de saber como fazer para que seja gerado uma nova library, utilizando o angular-cli na versão 6, com os arquivos que estão dentro de src/app.

Comment: tu chegou a fazer a migração do 5 para o 6? não sei o tamanho do seu projeto... mas se for viável crie um projeto novo na versão com o CLI e copie apenas código de regra e tal... ainda sim creio que terá que ajustar algo antes de gerar a lib

Comment: Sim foi exatamente o que fiz, fica mais fácil gerar um novo projeto com o cli e copiar apenas o código. Sim conseguir fazer alguns ajustes e funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

A solução para o problema acima descrito é encontrado neste site: [Angular-cli library](https://mereommig.dk/en/blog/adding-livereload-to-the-angular-cli-libraries). 
Neste site descreve o passo a passo como transformar uma biblioteca funcional no angular 6 com angular-cli.

1 - criar um projeto com ng new .

2 - usar o comando ng generate library  .

3 - importar os arquivos do seu projeto para a pasta projects//lib

4 - Trocar o nome do arquivo public_api.ts para index.ts.

5 - Dentro do arquivo ng-pakage.json trocar o nome public_api para index.

6 - No arquivo tsconfig.json, modificar dentro de path ->  adicionar o caminho /src.

7 - Rodar a biblioteca com o comando ng build .

Se tudo estiver configurado corretamente, será gerado uma bilbioteca dentro de dist. Com isso pode ser importado em outros projetos.